# Trying to make a reverse number-pattern, but having problem getting desired results

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to get a pattern like this but I am not getting desired results.

```
2
43
765
1110198
1110198
765
43
2
```

Here's the code:

```
n=int(input("enter the number"))
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print(j+1, end=" ")
    print()
for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print(j+1, end=" ")
    print()
```

This is what I am getting:

```
2 
3 2
4 3 2
5 4 3 2
5 4 3 2
4 3 2
3 2
2
```

Comment: There isn't enough context for me to determine how you're supposed to achieve the expected final result. It looks like it starts at 2, then counts backwards for two digits back to 2, then....something? What is supposed to happen here?

Comment: uhh sorry, it was my first ever question so I didnt exactly know how to explain. Anyway, I had to print a number pattern which printed half-diamond pattern but number goes in reverse, that '2' was actually a extra variable that had to be declared, I did post the code, you can check

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

```py
for i in range(1, n):
```

This will iterate `end-start` times - in this case `n-1` times. Remember that the second argument for `range` needs to be 1 element beyond where you want to end. Try this for various values of `x` and `y` to see how it will behave:

```py
print(list(range(x, y)))
```

---

Same thing here. Even when you're counting down your second argument should be 1 value beyond (lower in this case) than where you want to end.

```py
for j in range(i,0,-1):  # <-- might want to end at -1 instead of 0
```

---

If you don't want the spaces between numbers, don't add a space.

```py
print(j+1, end=" ")  # <-- why space?
# should probably be
print(j+1, end="")   # <-- empty string
```

---

Since the numbers you're printing simply count up from 2 it's much simpler to use an additional variable to keep track of the next number to print. Something like this:

```py
next_num = 2
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(next_num+i, next_num-1, -1):
        print(j, end="")
    next_num += i+1
    print()
```

---

Given all that, you should be able to put together the code to print the second half of the output on your own. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it helped a ton, finally made the correct pattern

Answer (score -1):

To those who might be needing the complete code:

```
new_num=int(input("enter the number"))
a_num=2
for i in range(new_num):
    for j in range(a_num+i,a_num-1,-1):
        print(j, end="")
    a_num+=i+1
    print("\r")
a_num=a_num-1
for i in range(new_num,0,-1):
    for j in range(a_num,a_num-i,-1):
        print(j, end="")
    a_num-=i
    print("\r")
```